# How to add Backorder in Customer account dashboard in magento 2.1?

Tags: magento-2.1, orders, sales-order, order-summary

[image]

I want to display backorder if any sku have backorder list.
See below screenshot:
For ITP7 SKU :
ordered :1
shipped : 1
backordered : 0

For ITP1 SKU :
ordered :1
shipped : 0
backordered : 1